# save input into web forms incase browser crash

Tags: browser-addons

Is there a way to automatically save web input just to protect from browser crashes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Option 1** copy the text in an input box (like this reply) to the clipboard before clicking submit. If your browser crashes, or the page times out, you can paste the text back into the text box.

**Option 2** use a mozilla-compatible browser (Firefox, Iceweasel, etc.) with the Lazarus add-on.

Comment: Great addon, exists for Google Chrome as well https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/loljledaigphbcpfhfmgopdkppkifgno

Answer (score 0):

The IEPro/IE7Pro add-in for Internet Explorer includes a "text saver" capability. This has not been updated since just after IE8 was distributed and doesn't appear to be compatible with IE9.